# Angular DOMContentLoaded is not fired if scripts are concatenated

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

There are several scripts after angular prod build: (runtime-es6, polyfills-es6, scripts, main-es6). I concatenated them to have one single script instead of 4 and inserted it in my index.html like that:

```
<script src="inject-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
```

It appeared that code from `main.ts`, where `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'...` is defined is not fired.

The typical answer on that is 'This is because `DOMContentLoaded` event has already fired by the time this code executed'.

My question **why**? What has changed when I simply concatenated these JS files?

I made a research and I completely confused. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) says that if `document.readyState === 'interactive'` the `DOMContentLoaded` already fired. What I did for test was adding `console.log` in `main.ts` to see the state before subscription is executed. **I tested with default build behavior, when index.html has all scripts files**

[image]

In the browser I saw

[image: Ready state is 'interactive']

The `readyState` is 'interactive'. How is that possible that event was fired? (The `readyState` is the same when I tested with concatenated files)

I can replace the code in `main.ts` to

```
document.readyState !== 'loading' ? bootstrap() : document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bootstrap);
```

And this will work. But I want to understand why do I have to?

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` event will wait for `<script>` tags to finish unless they are `<script async>` or dynamically added which can fire at anytime regardless of whether DOM is loaded or not. IDK Angular at all but I'm sure it plays a role.

Comment: @zer00ne do you know, why readyState is 'interactive' but the event is still fired?